# How to count how many particles in a 2D Gaussian distribution

Tags: python, numpy

I've just started using Python, so I'm sorry if I ask for trivial things.

I generated two random Gaussian distributions, and I used them to generate a 2D Gaussian distribution. What I'd like to do now is to plot a graph that represents the number of elements within a circumference of the 2D Gaussian distribution, varying the radius of the circumference (reducing it at each step).

You would be so kind to help me solve the problem. Thank you for taking my post into consideration.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

mu1, sigma1 = 0, 0.1                                  # mean and standard deviation
s1 = np.random.normal(mu1, sigma1, 10000)              # generate N randoomly Gaussian points
mu2, sigma2 = 0.8, 0.3
s2 = np.random.normal(mu2, sigma2, 10000)


#ISTOGRAMMA DI DUE DISTRIBUZIONI GAUSSIANE CON DIFFERENTI SET
plt.figure(1)
plt.title('Histogram of a 2D-Gaussian Distribution')
bins1 = plt.hist(s1, 100)
bins2 = plt.hist(s2, 100)
plt.show()

#DISTRIBUZIONE GAUSSIANA 2D
plt.figure(2)
plt.title('2D-Gaussian Distribution')
bins = plt.hist2d(s1, s2, 100)
cb = plt.colorbar()
cb.set_label('counts in bin')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Is this intentional that your 2D plot has a different scaling for x and y? It is quite misleading, because due to autoscale it always looks like as if sigma is the same in both distributions.

Comment: I'm sorry, ad I said I've recently started using Python and I probably made mistakes without being aware of it. If you can explain to me better what you mean for "different scaling for x and y" and "sigma" I would be happy to answer you with more clarifications. Thanks.

Comment: Well, your two distributions have a different sigma value (0.1 and 0.3). But in your 2D representation, one would guess that they are the same, because what we see is (due to autoscaling of matplotlib) a circle, not an ellipse. If you want to use the 2D graph only for yourself, there is no problem. If it is for a presentation, the reader might  misinterpret your graph.

Comment: Thanks for the correction and the interest. Here, this was a second problem, actually I should get an ellipse. There is no particular reason why I should use different sigma for the two distributions, it was just a test to generate two different distributions with different setting. I've tried to modify the script using the same sigma for both distributions, but the plot still keeps returning a circle insted of an ellipse.

Comment: You see the difference in sigma nicely in the first diagram, because they are plotted with the same scale. But the second plot hides the sigma difference. This is usually in terms of data presentation not advisable. Maybe you would like to ask another question?

Comment: Yes, certainly, maybe I modify the question in such a way that it can also be useful to other users

Comment: Please really ask a new question. A mixture of different questions leads only to confusion, which answer belongs to which question.

Comment: Ok, sorry, I'll do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick, assuming that s1 and s2 are the coordinates of some 2D points. If not, the code can be easily changed to match your problem.

First you center the two distributions by subtracting their mean, then you check which of their elements (absolute value) is inside the radius of your circle. You then take a logical and to make sure only to take the points that have both coordinates inside the circle.

```
radius = 0.1
valid_indexes = np.logical_and(abs(s1 -mu1)<= radius, abs(s2 - mu2) <= radius)

s1_valid = s1[valid_indexes]
s2_valid = s2[valid_indexes]
```

You have now obtained the points in the distributions that are inside a circle with given radius centered in (mu1, mu2).

[Edit]

As you want to count the number of elements, and not extract them, you can easily do

```
radius = 0.1
sum(np.logical_and(abs(s1 -mu1)< radius, abs(s2 - mu2) < radius))
```

[Edit 2]

This plots the number of points for every radius of the circle, starting from limit and reducing it by step until 0

```
step = 0.025
limit = 1

s1_ca = abs(s1-mu1)
s2_ca = abs(s2-mu2)

points_in_radius = []

radius_values = np.round(np.arange(0, limit, step), 3)[::-1]

for radius in radius_values:
    points_in_radius.append(sum(np.logical_and(s1_ca < radius, s2_ca < radius)))

plt.plot(points_in_radius)
plt.xticks(range(len(points_in_radius)), radius_values, rotation=90)
plt.show()
```

first i center the distributions and take their abs value. then I create the range of radiuses to use and finally I cycle through them and add the result using my above formula.

This is not the most efficient way to do it, but it works.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I'm probably not understanding the explanation you gave me or maybe I didn't explain as well as I should what I would like to get, I'll try to explain my self better. I generated two random Gaussian distributions, and I used them to generate a 2D Gaussian distribution. What I'd like to do now is to plot a graph that represents the number of elements within a circumference of the 2D Gaussian distribution, varying the radius of the circumference (reducing it at each step). Thanks a lot!!

Comment: So you want to start from a circle centered in (mu1, mu2), and from that create a plot that shows how many of the points in the 2d gaussian are into the circle each time you increase its radius by a step value?

Comment: YES is exactly what I would like to do, but instead of increasing the radius I would like to reduce it at each step.

Comment: Perfect @HitLuca, I tried now to modify the script thanks to your suggestions and it seems to actually plotting what I would like.
Thank you for the very clear explanation, but I have only one doubt about the creation of the range of rays to use "radius_values = np.round (np.arange (0, limit, step), 3) [:: - 1]" In particular, sorry for the incompetence, I don't understand what "[:: - 1]" is for.
Although this is not the most effective method it seems to me that it works properly.

Comment: It's just a quick way of reversing the values, as arange created them in ascending order

Comment: You could of course directly create the reversed order `np.arange(limit, 0, -step)`

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot! Nowit seems to be all clearer!